# How to use SplFileObject() with FTP?

Tags: php, ftp, splfileobject

This code runs very well with fopen:

```
<?php 

    $filename = "ftp://$ftp_user_name:$ftp_user_pass@$ftp_server/testes/TJ_IDA.TXT";
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);

    echo $contents;
```

But when I try with SplFileObject:

```
$file = new SplFileObject($filename,"r");
```

I got this error:

> Warning: Unknown: FTP server error 426:426 Failure writing network
>   stream. in Unknown on line 0

Is there another way to use SplFileObject with FTP?